# Invalid Scopes: email, openid, public_profile

Tags: android, ios, flutter, facebook

I am using `flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.8` to login into the app using my Facebook account. But when I try to log in, I am getting this.

"Invalid Scopes: email, openid, public_profile. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions%22)

[image]

Comment: There is no `openid` permission with Facebook's OAuth implementation.

Answer (score 32):

2023/8/9 latest solution

You probably forgot to add the email permission for your app in the Meta developer console.

Navigate to your app, then go to **'Use Case' -> 'Authentication and Account Creation'**, and add the email permission

Comment: I added the email permission still getting the error 'Sorry, something went wrong'. will you help me in this.

Comment: @rachna same for me. I can't add the email permission and got that error

Comment: Maybe you guys didn't fill data usage questions?

Answer (score 9):

After struggling I've finally found how to fix it.
It's an issue related to the settings of Facebook login for Business.

**Fix : Switch from "Facebook login for Business" to "Facebook Login" inside developer.facebook.com**

It seems that Facebook login for Business is not supported yet for flutter_facebook_auth on Flutter.

**Source : https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/388**

Comment: flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.8

Answer (score 4):

Example Usecase Image from Facebook Dashboard

[image]

Sometimes you have selected Facebook business as Login which we need to change into Facebook login by default and sometimes you havent providied the Valid Scope from Facebook that you want to use in the app. For example Email,ProfileURL you need to specify in the details of the scope in Facebook usecase by adding new scope

Comment: this should been an answer for those who still get this 'Invalid Scopes' issues even if they are using Facebook Login

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround I using for my flutter app incase you need to use the "Facebook login for Business":

- Ensure your Business status is verified..
- Making a landing page with one button using Javascript SDK for login and redirect to app using deep-link include the access token.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party , but this is the same problem we faced in our unity app, first you need to make sure facebook business account is verified under **Review --> Verification**, next you want to fill out contact details and data deletion instructions url under App Settings --> Basic Settings, Also in use cases add the **(gaming_profile, gaming_user_picture)** and **(user_friends)** for your invalid scope error prompt screen , which only happens if you are the admin of the app you need to add those permission in the code

**{ "gaming_profile", "user_friends" }**

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem after installing cocoapod on my Apple silicon Xcode build folder by creating another fb account and logged in on that on my iPhone and all worked as expected after exporting the project.

This is Unity but maybe the solution is the same.