# Invalid Scopes: openid error with Flutter - Facebook Login for Business

Tags: flutter, facebook, authentication, openid, flutter-facebook-login

I am developing a Flutter app and I am using the **flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.0.2** package to integrate Facebook login. I am using the **"Facebook Login for Business"** product in my Meta developer account and I am getting the following error message:

#### `Invalid Scopes: openid. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions`

I have checked the Facebook documentation for valid permissions, but I am still not sure how to fix this error. I am using Flutter version 3.13.7 and Dart version 3.1.3.

Has anyone else encountered this error? How can I fix it?

[image: screenshot of the error message]

#### I am using the following code to perform Facebook login

```
final LoginResult facebookLoginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login(
permissions: ["public_profile", "email"],
);
switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
    case LoginStatus.failed:
        _onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.log('Facebook Login Error: ${facebookLoginResult.message!}');
        break;
    case LoginStatus.cancelled:
        _onLoginStatusChanged(false);
        break;
    case LoginStatus.success:
        ResponseObject? response = await UserService.userFacebookLogin(
            facebookLoginResult.accessToken!.token,
        );
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.success!) {
                //success
            }
        } else {
            //error
        }
        break;
    case LoginStatus.operationInProgress:
        //Login is in progress!
        break;
}
```

Comment: Please checkout this answer it might be helpful :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76864493/19807154